# Access dynamic input name in ImmutableMultiDict

Tags: python, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I have this from wtforms:

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('csrf_token', u'1422930083.22##139a472d31a0bbb37c25fee616b8b5bd5a38e37a'), ('27', u'y'), ('type', u'job')])
```

I can do

```
print request.form.getlist('type')
```

to get the type value. But how about the `27`? The name can change, so in another form could be the `25`.

How can i access that input field? ImmutableMultiDict could be converted? I can't pop any element in `ImmutableMultiDict`

```
TypeError: 'ImmutableMultiDict' objects are immutable
```

Comment: if you have `a = ImmutableMultiDict([(...)]` why not just access 27 as `a['27']`?

Comment: @Marcin i don't know what is the input name. could be 27, or another number.

Comment: So how do you know it has 'type' name? if you dont know other keys in the dict, you have to iterate over it, and get everything.

Comment: @Marcin the form has 3 items. two inputs (type and csrf) have always the same key. The unique key with a variable name is the other (27, or something else).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way works fine for me:

```
data_form = {}

for fieldname, value in request.form.items():
    data_form[fieldname] = value

data_form.pop("csrf_token", None)
data_form.pop("type", None)

print data_form
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help. Normally I dont work with ImmutableMultiDict so maybe there is better way. But assuming that the dict has 3 elements always, and two of them are 'csrf_token' and 'type', the name of the third, unknown key you can obtain as follows:

```
from  werkzeug.datastructures import ImmutableMultiDict

imd = ImmutableMultiDict([('csrf_token', u'1422930083.22##139a472d31a0bbb37c25fee616b8b5bd5a38e37a'), 
                          ('27', u'y'), 
                          ('type', u'job')])

for k in imd:
    if k not in ['csrf_token','type']:
        last_key = k
        print(last_key)
        break

print(imd[last_key])
```

The result is:

```
27
y
```

Note that looping is needed, as dicts are unordered, so you never known in  what order keys in a dict are stored.